# im trying to send authentication request for apple using python and django 1.9, but always giving me unsupported_grant_type

Tags: python, django, web-deployment, django-allauth, sign-in-with-apple

I'm trying to send authentication request for apple using Python and Django 1.9, but always giving me `unsupported_grant_type`:

```py
def login_with_apple(self, code):
    apple_url = "https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token"
    client_secret = generate_apple_client_secret()
    adapter = AppleOAuth2Adapter(self.request)
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    data = {'client_id': settings.CLIENT_ID,
            'client_secret': client_secret,
            'code': code,
            'grand_type': 'authorization_code'}

    resp = requests.post(url=apple_url, data=data, headers=headers)
    access_token = None
    if resp.status_code in [200, 201]:
        try:
            access_token = resp.json()
        except ValueError:
            access_token = dict(parse_qsl(resp.text))
    if not access_token or 'acces_token' not in access_token:
        raise OAuth2Error(
            'Error retrieving access token: %s' % resp.content
        )
    return access_token
```

How I generates my `client_secret`:

```py
def generate_apple_client_secret():
    now = datetime.utcnow()
    claims = {
                'iss': settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_TEAM_ID,
                'aud': 'https://appleid.apple.com',
                'iat': now,
                'exp': now + timedelta(days=180),
                'sub': settings.CLIENT_ID,
                }
    headers = {'kid': settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_KEY_ID, 'alg': 'HS256'}
    client_secret = jwt.encode(
                payload=claims, key=settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_PRIVATE_KEY, 
                algorithm='HS256', 
                **strong text** headers=headers).decode('utf-8')
    return client_secret
```

I'm sending a request to apple but always giving me this error:

```
user = self.login_with_apple(ser.instance.token)
File "/home/omar/PycharmProjects/Aswaq/oscarapi/views/login.py", line 488, in  
login_with_apple
Error retrieving access token: %s' % resp.content
OAuth2Error: Error retrieving access token: {"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens, the ES256 algorithm should be used.